# How to measure total amount of memory used by userspace processes in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory

How to measure total amount of memory allocated to user space programs in Linux? That is size of all memory pages that userspace programs have in real memory.

`/proc/meminfo` doesn't seem to provide this info.

Currently I am adding `rss` fields of all processes from `/proc/$pid/stat` but that does not take into account shared memory pages.

*Update:* By "user space" I mean processes run by all users, including root (as opposed to kernel space).

Comment: Does *"real memory"* include *swap* devices?

Comment: @agc: no, only memory that would be included in RSS but without duplicate shared pages. In other words, number of bytes on RAM sticks allocated to user processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`smem`](http://www.selenic.com/smem/) to show a total of all user memory, no swap, and not counting any shared memory twice:

```
sudo smem -c pss -t | tail -1
```

Output on my system:

```
4119846
```

Unrolling that:

- `-c pss` selects the column, in this case *PSS*.  From `man smem`:

  ```
        smem reports physical memory usage, taking shared memory  pages
        into  account.   Unshared memory is reported as the USS (Unique
        Set Size).  Shared memory is divided evenly among the processes
        sharing   that  memory.   The  unshared  memory  (USS)  plus  a
        process's proportion of shared memory is reported  as  the  PSS
        (Proportional Set Size).  The USS and PSS only include physical
        memory usage.  They do not include memory that has been swapped
        out to disk.
  ```

  - `-t` shows a *total* or sum of all PSS used at the end, and `tail -1` nips off the preceding data.

To show just the total *unshared* user memory, replace `-c pss` with `-c uss`:

```
sudo smem -c uss -t | tail -1
```

Output:

```
 3874356
```

---

Note the above PSS total is more or less the same number as shown in *row #5, column #2* here:

```
smem -w
```

Output:

```
Area                           Used      Cache   Noncache 
firmware/hardware                 0          0          0 
kernel image                      0          0          0 
kernel dynamic memory       1367712    1115708     252004 
userspace memory            4112112     419884    3692228 
free memory                  570060     570060          0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to include root processes as well? I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a one-liner that I use, shows you what process uses how much Swap and the PID:

```
for file in /proc/*/status;
do
    awk '/VmSwap|Tgid|Name/ {printf "%s %s %s", $2, $3, $4} END { print "" }' "$file";
done | sort -k 3 -n -r | head -20
```

<sub>(I've split it here over several lines for readability. You can simply join all the lines together if you prefer it as one line.)</sub>

Comment: That code doesn't provide a *total* amount.